# Firebase registration token is empty?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to add push notification support for my Android app. I think [Ravi Tramada's code](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/) makes a nice starting point, so I take it.

Basically I just copied his code. I've added both **MyFirebaseInstanceID.java** and **MyFirebaseMessagingService.java** as service in AndroidManifest.xml. Nothing happens. Every time I run the app, it always says "Firebase reg ID is not recieved yet" .

I've uploaded the whole app to this [repository](https://github.com/anta40/firebasetest/tree/master/android/app). Could someone enlighten my what goes wrong here?

Comment: first uninstall old apk then install new

Comment: I did that. Uninstalled the app on the phone, then reinstall again (via Android studio). Nothing changed. OK, just found out that sending message  via Firebase Console didn't work either :/

Answer (score 0):

I show your code in GitHub

> Write your service inside application tag like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
     <!-- Firebase Notifications -->
<service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>

<service android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
<!-- ./Firebase Notifications -->
</application> 
</manifest>
```